# Jquery and IIFE wrapper clarification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `window` can not be redefined  like we see in this example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYX0p.jpg
[image]

So why jquery starts itself with `window`  ( and it even uses the same name)?

`(function( window, undefined ) {...})( window );`

I mean , it could have use `window` inside it...

*p.s. the `undefined` trick has nothing to do with it...*

Comment: alex , so why it doesnt send `this` ?

Comment: @alex23 by muiltiple windows you mean actually Iframes. but if i add jquery into the main window , should there still be a problem .?

Comment: Is it not plausible that `window` may be redefinable in the future?  I wouldn't rule out that possibility and would therefore appreciate all my websites not breaking due to an updated or popular new browser.

Comment: @Archer if someone in the future will allow `window` to redefine , value will get passed to the function  itself with along with the modified value.please look at the code more closely.

Comment: You could end up with 2 different meaning for `window` though - that's what I way saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a possible explanation is to make JQuery easier to port in other contexts, where the global object may not be named `window`, or even embedded in some other scripts, in the case `window` refers to a valid token in the current scope (or in the activation object).

Anyway, the only reason why I think this may be useful is because the jQuery code can use the `window`name without worry,  because any vendor can bind the name to whatever object it wants, only by changing a single line of the jQuery source (the last one).

Comment: I don't have any. Just guessing. This is called *the module pattern*, where the code is encapsulated in a function and doesn't access any name other than its formal parameters. Without modifying the last line, it makes no sense to me, because the parameter and the argument are named the same